# How do I construct a url from the current month and year for redirecting user to page for current month?

Tags: url, date, redirect

I publish a new page on my site each month and the pages are all in the form:

.../[month]_[year]/index.php

I have written a simple file, called latest.html, which redirects the user to the page for the latest month (so that they can always use the same URL to get to the latest page) by including:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/july_2012">
```

But, obviously, I need to update this manually each month.  I am wondering how I would go about automating this, so that the URL is automatically generated based on the current month/date on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest.html file you could use:

```
<?php

header('Location: '.date('m', time()).'_'.date('Y', time()).'/index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way of returning the month in the form 'july' rather than '07'?

Comment: OK, I worked it out: `header('Location: '.strtolower(date('F', time())).'_'.date('Y', time()).'/index.php');`  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can check based on the month and year, then you replace the page

Example, if you have 4 months:

```
jan.php
feb.php 
march.php 
april.php
```

Simply use the following code in `index.php`.

```
<?php
    $date =date('m-Y');
    if( $date =='01-2012' ){
        include('jan,php');}
    else if($date=='02-2012'){
        include('feb,php');}
    elseif (some condtion){
        ....
    }
    else{
        include('index,php');
    }
?>
```

It may be helpful if you try it this way.